# If two ideals agree on $K\lhd R$ and yield the same quotients $\pi_K(I)=\pi_K(J)$, are they equal?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

Inspired by my lectures on the basics of commutative algebra, I tried to investigate whether the noetherian property still holds when taking extensions (here meaning: if $I\lhd R$ and $R/I$ both satisfy the a.c.c., does $R$ as well?). I started to wonder the following:

> Let $I,J,K\lhd R$, and $\pi_K: R \to R/K$ the canonical projection. If $I\cap K = J\cap K$ and $\pi_K(I) = \pi_K (J)$, does this already imply $I = J$?

We can represent this graphically via the short exact sequence of $R$-Modules $$
0 \to K\stackrel{\iota}{\to} R \stackrel{\pi_K}{\to} R/K \to 0
$$ where $\iota$ is just the embedding of $K$ into $R$, and notice that the intersections $I\cap K, J\cap K$ is basically just the preimages under $\iota$.

I tried to consider all these objects as $R$-moduls and play around with isomorphism theorems, but I only got statements for quotiens or intersections of $I, J, I+J$ or similar, but not these objects directly.

Is it even true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not true.  For instance, let $R=k[x,y]/(x^2,xy,y^2)$ for some field $k$, and let $K=(x)$, $I=(y)$, and $J=(x+y)$.  Then $R/K\cong k[y]/(y^2)$ and $\pi_K(I)=\pi_K(J)=(y)$, and also $I\cap K=J\cap K=0$, but $I\neq J$.

It is true, though, if you know that $I\subseteq J$, which is what you need for proving that Noetherianness is preserved by extensions.  Indeed, given $j\in J$, there exists $i\in I$ such that $\pi_K(i)=\pi_K(j)$.  Then $i-j\in K$, and also $i-j\in J$ since $i,j\in J$ (here we use the assumption that $I\subseteq J$).  Thus $i-j\in J\cap K=I\cap K$ and so $j=i-(i-j)\in I$.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have an example where $R$ is a domain? If I see correctly, $k[x,y]/(x^2,xy,y^2)$ is essentially a three-dimensional $k$-algebra with trivial multiplication, so everything that's not in the $k$ part is a zero divisor.

Comment: You can get an example where $R$ is a domain by just pulling all of these ideals back to $k[x,y]$.

Comment: That's a good point, thanks again.